# Cartesian product of two lists

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

Given a map where a digit is associated to several characters

```
scala> val conversion = Map("0" -> List("A", "B"), "1" -> List("C", "D"))
conversion: scala.collection.immutable.Map[java.lang.String,List[java.lang.String]] =
  Map(0 -> List(A, B), 1 -> List(C, D))
```

I want to generate all possible character sequences based on a sequence of digits. Examples:

```
"00" -> List("AA", "AB", "BA", "BB")
"01" -> List("AC", "AD", "BC", "BD")
```

I can do this with for comprehensions

```
scala> val number = "011"
number: java.lang.String = 011
```

Create a sequence of possible characters per index

```
scala> val values = number map { case c => conversion(c.toString) }
values: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[List[java.lang.String]] =
  Vector(List(A, B), List(C, D), List(C, D))
```

Generate all the possible character sequences

```
scala> for {
     | a <- values(0)
     | b <- values(1)
     | c <- values(2)
     | } yield a+b+c
res13: List[java.lang.String] = List(ACC, ACD, ADC, ADD, BCC, BCD, BDC, BDD)
```

Here things get ugly and it will only work for sequences of three digits. Is there any way to achieve the same result for any sequence length?

Comment: Strictly speaking, what you are trying to get is not a cartesian product. If you have `List[T]`, you do not guarantee the size, and also the list should be homogeneous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following suggestion is not using a for-comprehension. But I don't think it's a good idea after all, because as you noticed you'd be tied to a certain length of your cartesian product.

```
scala> def cartesianProduct[T](xss: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] = xss match {
     |   case Nil => List(Nil)
     |   case h :: t => for(xh <- h; xt <- cartesianProduct(t)) yield xh :: xt
     | }
cartesianProduct: [T](xss: List[List[T]])List[List[T]]

scala> val conversion = Map('0' -> List("A", "B"), '1' -> List("C", "D"))
conversion: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,List[java.lang.String]] = Map(0 -> List(A, B), 1 -> List(C, D))

scala> cartesianProduct("01".map(conversion).toList)
res9: List[List[java.lang.String]] = List(List(A, C), List(A, D), List(B, C), List(B, D))
```

#### Why not tail-recursive?

Note that above recursive function is **not** tail-recursive. This isn't a problem, as `xss` will be short unless you have a lot of singleton lists in `xss`. This is the case, because the size of the result grows exponentially with the number of non-singleton elements of `xss`.

Answer (score 5):

I could come up with this:

```
val conversion = Map('0' -> Seq("A", "B"), '1' -> Seq("C", "D"))

def permut(str: Seq[Char]): Seq[String] = str match {
  case Seq()  => Seq.empty
  case Seq(c) => conversion(c)
  case Seq(head, tail @ _*) =>
    val t = permut(tail)
    conversion(head).flatMap(pre => t.map(pre + _))
}

permut("011")
```

Comment: Thanks Sciss, I accepted ziggystar's answer since he posted it before and both answers are pretty good. I especially like your idea of decomposing the `for` in a chain of `flatMaps`.

Comment: @Mark Sciss' answer differs only syntactically from mine (at least for the part building the combinations). He uses `map` and `flatMap` and I use the for-comprehension syntactic sugar, which gets translated to Sciss' code by the compiler. Only other difference is that I have extracted a method for the cartesian product.

Comment: @ziggystar Great, now I understand better what is happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I just did that as follows and it works

```
    def cross(a:IndexedSeq[Tree], b:IndexedSeq[Tree]) = {
        a.map (p => b.map( o => (p,o))).flatten
    }
```

Don't see the $Tree type that am dealing it works for arbitrary collections too..