# Composing a list of all pairs

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I'm brand new to Scala, having had very limited experience with functional programming through Haskell.

I'd like to try composing a list of all possible pairs constructed from a single input list. Example:

```
val nums = List[Int](1, 2, 3, 4, 5)   // Create an input list
val pairs = composePairs(nums)        // Function I'd like to create

// pairs == List[Int, Int]((1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 1) ... etc)
```

I tried using `zip` on each element with the whole list, hoping that it would duplicate the one item across the whole. It didn't work (only matched the first possible pair). I'm not sure how to repeat an element (Haskell does it with `cycle` and `take` I believe), and I've had trouble following the documentation on Scala.

This leaves me thinking that there's probably a more concise, functional way to get the results I want. Does anybody have a good solution?

Comment: It's very helpful to learn the terminology for the operation you want to perform. In this case, you are trying to find the product of the list with itself. Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217764/cartesian-product-of-two-lists

Comment: @Marcin Thank you. I've found one of the biggest stumbling blocks towards learning any degree of functional programming is picking up the new terminology.

Comment: Cross product? Same as Cartesian product? If Spark is relevant here , then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26565173/1175496) is also relevant

Answer (score 30, accepted):

How about this:

```
val pairs = for(x <- nums; y <- nums) yield (x, y)
```

Comment: Works spectacularly. I'm not entirely sure *why* it works though. Is `for (x <- nums; y <- nums)` like a concise way of saying `for (x <- nums) for (y <- nums)`?

Comment: @KChaloux: It's syntactic sugar for `nums.flatMap(x => nums.map((x, _)))`, which is essentially `nums.map(x => nums.map((x, _))).flatten`, if that helps.

Comment: @dbyrne It's definitely insight I could use.

Answer (score 11):

For those of you who don't want duplicates:

```
val uniquePairs = for {
      (x, idxX) <- nums.zipWithIndex
      (y, idxY) <- nums.zipWithIndex
      if idxX < idxY
    } yield (x, y)

val nums = List(1,2,3,4,5)
uniquePairs: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5))
```

Comment: You want `<=`.   Your output's missing (e.g.) `(1,1)`

Comment: One may see `(x,x)` as duplicate in some cases. Adding `<=` or replacing to `>`, `>=` should be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version using map and flatten

`val pairs = nums.flatMap(x => nums.map(y => (x,y)))`

`List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3), (3,4), (3,5), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (4,5), (5,1), (5,2) (5,3), (5,4), (5,5))`

This can then be easily wrapped into a composePairs function if you like:

```
def composePairs(nums: Seq[Int]) =
    nums.flatMap(x => nums.map(y => (x,y)))
```

Comment: Better just use `flatMap(...)` instead of `map(...).flatten`.