# How to build a collection based on Cartesian product of all elements of other collections?

Tags: java, scala, collections

Can You share any good solution for creating immutable collection in Scala based on full iteration of items in several arrays/another collections?

E.g. in Java you can use:

```
List<String> signals = ...;
List<SignalState> states = ...;

List<SignalAndState> result = new ArrayList<~>(signals.size() * states.size());

for (String signal: signals) {
  for (SignalState state: states) {
    // some if() condition or process() function can be here 
    result.add(new SignalAndState(signal, state))
  }
}
```

What are the best practices of building smth like this using Scala?
The same approach (using for() in for()) is bad idea, I think, and is not compatible with object-functional nature of Scala language at all.

Comment: What you compute is basically the Cartesian product of two sequences. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217764/cartesian-product-of-two-lists or http://anders.janmyr.com/2009/10/lists-in-scala.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about the best practice, but one way you could accomplish this is to us a use a `for` comprehension to create the collection you are looking for:

```
val signals = List[String](...)
val states = List[SignalState](...)

for(signal <- signals; state <- states) yield new SignalAndState(signal, state)
```

That should yield a `List[SignalAndState]` with all the elements

Alternately, you could use a `flatMap` and `map` to accomplish the same result, like:

```
signals flatMap ( signal => states map ( state => new SignalAndState(signal, state)))
```

Comment: by the way, the code above (the one with for comprehension) will be internally translated by the compiler into second one with flatMap/map

Comment: Why using a List in Scala since List in Scala and Java are totally different? List in Scala is implemented as a LinkedList