# N to N matching in scala

Tags: scala

I have two lists, namely

```
val a = List(1,2,3)

val b = List(4,5)
```

I want to perform N to N bipartite mapping and want to get output

```
List((1,4),(1,5),(2,4),(2,5),(3,4),(3,5))
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `B` a list or a pair? And why would you want the output to be a tuple instead of a list?

Comment: Values are tagged with lower case names by convention.

Comment: B is a list. I am trying to find alternative for two nested "foreach" operation.

Comment: FYI, what you're looking for is the *cartesian product* of two lists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross product in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740199/cross-product-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that `B = List(4,5)`, then you can use for comprehensions to achieve your goal:

```scala
val A = List(1,2,3)
val B = List(4,5)

val result = for(a <- A; b <- B) yield {
  (a, b)
}
```

The output is

```
result:List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (1,5), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5))
```

Comment: Glad that I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider also

```
a.flatMap(x => b.map(y => (x,y)))
```

though not so concise as a for comprehension.