# Make List whose sublists cover all combinations of two input Lists

Tags: scala

I am trying to make combinations (Please let me know if the terminology that I am using can be improved), such that we every element of the result list is a combination of two input lists, and the result list covers all the possible combinations.

The elements are not allowed to move around, the the first element of a sublist is first element of either input List, the second element of a sublist is second element of either sublist, and so on..

Example 1:

Input: `List(1,1,1)` and `List(0,0,0)` (we can assume that lists have same length)

Output:

```
List(List(1, 1, 1),
 List(1, 1, 0),
 List(1, 0, 1),
 List(0, 1, 1),
 List(1, 0, 0),
 List(0, 1, 0),
 List(0, 0, 1),
 List(0, 0, 0))
```

Example 2:

Input: `List(1,2,3)` and `List(4,5,6)`

Output:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3),
 List(1, 2, 6),
 List(1, 5, 3),
 List(1, 5, 6),
 List(4, 5, 6),
 List(4, 5, 3),
 List(4, 2, 3),
 List(4, 2, 6))
```

My current solution only works on the simple case (Example 1):

```
  def makeCombinations(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): List[List[Int]] = {
    val N = a.length
    (0 to N).map(x => a.slice(x, N) ::: b.slice(0, x)).flatMap(x => x.permutations).toList

  }
```

What is the best way to approach this?

I am not looking to find a `cross product`, which would result in:

```
List(List(1, 4),
     List(1, 5),
     List(1, 6),
     List(2, 4),
     List(2, 5),
     List(2, 6),
     List(3, 4),
     List(3, 5),
     List(3, 6))
```

This questions is different from: [Cross product in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740199/cross-product-in-scala)

Comment: When you say "all possible combinations", are elements from the input lists allowed to move around are they? So would `List(1,2,3)` be in the output of combining `List(2,2,2)` and `List(3,3,1)`? What about reusing elements? Is `List(1,1,1)` in the output of `List(1,2,3)` and `List(4,5,6)`?

Comment: @Alec, good point, no they  are not allowed to move around (which invalidates my code for the the example I provided). I will update my question shortly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross product in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740199/cross-product-in-scala)

Comment: @Mika'il, I edited my question, I don't believe this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps less efficient than `foldRight` version, but easier to understand as a start:

```
//almost same as your List(0,0,0) List(1,1,1)
def combos(n: Int): List[List[Boolean]] = (1 to n).foldLeft(List(List.empty[Boolean])){
  case (acc, _) => acc.map(false :: _) ::: acc.map(true :: _)
}

//apply combo (like 1,1,0) to choose element from either of lists
def applyCombo(a: List[Int], b: List[Int])(combo: List[Boolean]): List[Int] = 
  a zip b zip combo map { case ((x, y), b) => if (b) x else y }

//get all combinations (as boolean) and apply them to a and b
def combine(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]) = combos(a.size) map applyCombo(a, b)
```

Putting it together, getting rid of intermediate `List[List[Boolean]]` and adding `foldRight`:

```
def combine(aL: List[Int], bL: List[Int]) = (aL zip bL).foldRight(List(List.empty[Int])){
  case ((a, b), acc) => acc.map(a :: _) ::: acc.map(b :: _)
}
```

Experiment:

```
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
b: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)
res73_3: List[List[Int]] = List(
  List(1, 2, 3),
  List(1, 2, 6),
  List(1, 5, 3),
  List(1, 5, 6),
  List(4, 2, 3),
  List(4, 2, 6),
  List(4, 5, 3),
  List(4, 5, 6)
)
```

Note:

`:::` isn't much efficient, it could be replaced with `acc.flatMap(x => List(a :: x, b :: x))` if you don't care about order of combinations.

Comment: Does it make a difference if we use `foldRight` or `foldLeft` in the final `combine` function? couldn't the solution be like this:                            `def combine2(aL: List[Int], bL: List[Int]) = (aL zip bL).foldLeft(List(List.empty[Int])){
    case (acc, (a,b)) => acc.map(a :: _) ::: acc.map(b :: _)
  }`

Comment: @Akavall `foldLeft` just flips sublists: instead of `List(1,2,3)`, you'd get `List(3,2,1)`, so you would have to reverse it or add new element to the end, which is inefficient for lists.

Comment: But reversing is fairly easy: `def combine2(aL: List[Int], bL: List[Int]) = (aL zip bL).foldLeft(List(List.empty[Int])){
    case (acc, (a,b)) => acc.map(_ :+ a) ::: acc.map(_ :+ b)
  }`

Comment: Is my above suggested solution roughly equivalent to what your `foldRight` solution?

Comment: @Akavall it's equivalent, but much slower: `x :+ a` takes linear time - it traverses the whole `x`, `a :: x` takes constant time  - it just links head (a) to a list x. See: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: So it is not really equivalent! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to look at it: you want to zip together the input lists, then you want to walk the resulting list of tuples, `flatMap`ing along the way to try all combinations. The way to do this efficiently on a `List` is using `foldRight`.

```
def combine[A](xs: List[A], ys: List[A]): List[List[A]] =
  (xs zip ys).foldRight(List(List[A]()))(
    (xy, zss) => for (z <- List(xy._1, xy._2); zs <- zss) yield (z :: zs)
  )
```

Trying it out at the REPL:

```
scala> Test.combine(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6))
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 6), List(1, 5, 3),
List(1, 5, 6), List(4, 2, 3), List(4, 2, 6), List(4, 5, 3), List(4, 5, 6))
```

Comment: In Haskell, this is much neater: `combine xs ys = foldr (\(x,y) zss -> (:) <$> [x,y] <*> zss) [[]] $ zip xs ys`