# Cartesian product between list inside a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming, cartesian-product

Input:

```
[[a,b,c],
[d,e,],
[f,g,h]
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
[a,d,f],[a,d,g],[a,d,h],.......[c,e,h]
].
```

How would you do this in Scala?

Edit: The size of the individual list containing each letter, and the size of the list  containing the list, is random. The lists containing letter can have different sizes

Comment: What have you tried? There will always be three lists? Or there could be as many of them?

Comment: There could be many. 
I haven't tried any since when I think of something I quickly realise it doesn't work. 
But I have started to write a function that call it recursively, where the inputs are the first list, and the rest of the list.

Comment: Try to solve the problem by hand, until you can identify an algorithm. Then start to code that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217764/cartesian-product-of-two-lists. The question's asking for only 2 lists, but the top answer at least has a solution that works for multiple lists. There's also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14740199/cross-product-in-scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is generic for element type but specific for collection type, i.e. `List`.

```
def cProd[T](in: List[List[T]]): List[List[T]] =
  in.foldRight(List(List.empty[T])) {
    for {word <- _ ; sentence <- _} yield word :: sentence
  }
```

It can be made more general for collection type but you'd likely loose some `List` optimizations.

Comment: Perfect! so short and nice

Answer (score 1):

Using Cats with List:

```
import cats.Semigroupal
import cats.instances.list._

Semigroupal[List]
  .product(Semigroupal[List]
    .product(List("a","b","c"), List("d","e","")),(List("f","g","h")))
  .flatten {case ((a,b), c) => List((a,b,c))}
```

Comment: The thing is, we don't know how long lists are. (the outside list, nor the inside lists).